# How to differentiate TCP and UDP packets in machine with java code?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, tcp, udp

How to differentiate the TCP and UDP packets before sending it to the internet using java? I need to listen to those packets and differentiate whether it is TCP or UDP. How to achieve this using Java code?

UPDATE:
I need to redirect all the TCP/IP and UDP packects to a server (Ip) and need to track the traffic of the TCP/IP and UDP Packets and make a log.

Answer (score 3):

You can't see individual packet with TCP in Java but when you are using a Socket it will be TCP and if you are using a DatagramSocket it will be UDP. i.e. the classes are different so there is no hcance you will confuse them.

If you want to snoop a network adapter to see which type of packets are being sent, you can use JPCap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to redirect all the TCP/IP and UDP packects to a server (Ip) and need to track the traffic of the TCP/IP and UDP Packets and make a log.

Comment: In that case you should have the server log all the data it sends and receives.  Trying to do this externally is tricky at best and I wouldn't suggest you do it unless you have many years of network programming experience i.e. you have to use a native library and write allot of code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are listening for the packets on a socket, you need to specify the socket type.

`java.net.DatagramSocket` for UDP,  and `java.net.Socket` for TCP, so you will always know what type of packet you are getting.  Or are you looking to sniff traffic, and differentiate that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to redirect all the TCP/IP and UDP packects to a server (Ip) and need to track the traffic of the TCP/IP and UDP Packets and make a log.

Comment: Well you would then need to run in promiscuous to be able to listen to all that traffic, and as @peter lawrey says, use something like jpcap if you need to do it in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

if you can read the ip packet header info, you can get it done.
In ip packet header includes the next protocol no(6 means TCP,17 means UDP), you should use this to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it will derease the performance,if I read each packet.

Comment: It depands on your hardware. If your machine is switch or router, it's a piece of cake. Else if yours is PC or Server, as your word, it will decrease the performance rather than non-reading every pkt proccessing. My ex job is tester about the network product, and i dont know any other way to slove your problem, sorry.

Comment: @2vision2 - have you actually thought through your requirements? Because you've stated a very clear requirement to log each packet, then you say it will decrease performance if you read each packet. How do you expect to log them without reading them?

Comment: if you are just reading packets headers and not bodies, it really isn't that hard,  but if all you need to do is log this info, something like tcpdump or ngrep might solve your problem without having to write much if any code. but as @parsifal says, I think you need to further refine your actual requirements.